# Pandas get column values of last N records as a list from another dataframe based on current row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master dataframe

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame({'Student' : [1000, 1001, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1001],
                      'Subject':  ['ENG','MATH','ENG','MATH','MATH','ENG'],                                 
                          'Score' : np.random.random(6)})
```

df looks like below:

```
   Student  Subject Score
0   1000    ENG     0.913371
1   1001    MATH    0.806932
2   1000    ENG     0.911395
3   1001    MATH    0.292194
4   1001    MATH    0.796219
5   1001    ENG     0.071908
```

I have another dataframe

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'Student' : [1000, 1001, 1000, 1002, 1001],
                      'Subject':  ['ENG','ENG','MATH','MATH','MATH']})
```

df looks like below:

```
    Student Subject
0   1000    ENG
1   1001    ENG
2   1000    MATH
3   1002    MATH
4   1001    MATH
```

Expected result:

```
       Student  Subject Last_3_Scr
    0   1000    ENG     [0.911395, 0.913371]
    1   1001    ENG     [0.071908]
    2   1000    MATH    []
    3   1002    MATH    []
    4   1001    MATH    [0.796219,0.292194,0.806932]
```

I tried

```
my_df = my_df.sort_values('Student')
my_df['Last_3_Scr'] = [x.agg(list) for x in
                  master_df.groupby(['Student','Subject'])['Score'].rolling(3)]
```

But not working as expected. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
my_df.set_index(['Student', 'Subject']).join(master_df.groupby(['Student', 'Subject']).agg(lambda x: list(x)[-3:])).reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Student Subject                                              Score
0     1000     ENG          [0.35104403633346903, 0.1978421698809576]
1     1001     ENG                               [0.4159411753678969]
2     1000    MATH                                                NaN
3     1002    MATH                                                NaN
4     1001    MATH  [0.4051361256846634, 0.23072043308688617, 0.67...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One small correction I had to do in my real dataset is to discard all column Student, Subject & Points before I do groupby.